# adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner() returns null on some Android 6.0 devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My App works with BLE devices and searches them in the following way (API 21+):

```
adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, scanSettings, this);
```

It works just perfect for most devices (f.e. Samsung) but returns `null` on some LGE and HTC devices (with Android 6.0) and crashes:

> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(java.util.List, android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings, android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference

The app is targeted to pre-marshmallow android so the premissions are (should be) granted.

Comment: getBluetoothLeScanner return null if the bluetooth adapter is disabled

Comment: that's strange because i do enable it in the very beginning: `// turn BLE on
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Enabling BLE adapter");
            adapter.enable();
        }`

Comment: I assume you have the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission. And did you check the return value of the enable() call ?

Comment: yes, sure. it works on most devices with no code changes.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might call startScan just right after adapter.enable().
Because BluetoothAdapter.enable() is an asynchronous call, so you might get NullPointer exception, you can try to register broadcast receiver to receive BluetoothAdapter status, something like below.

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                    BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    //to check if BluetoothAdapter is enable by your code
                    if(enableFlag){
                      adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, scanSettings, callBack);
                    }
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What does the "enableFlag" do?

Comment: just a flag to check Bluetooth was enabled by your code.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to enable Bluetooth by doing this:

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
```

I've noticed that if Bluetooth isn't enabled on the device, mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner(); returns null. You can enable Bluetooth by running the above code, which generates an Activity to allow the user enable it, or the user can go to their settings and turn on Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 6.0, your app must have a new permission to access the BT adapter:
[Android 6.0 - Access to Hardware Identifier](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).
And since Android 6.0 as well, permissions need to be requested at runtime, not during app install: [Android 6.0 - Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
    fun startScan(filters: List<ScanFilter>) {
      val isAdapterEnabled = getBluetoothAdapter().isEnabled()
      if (!isScanRunning && isAdapterEnabled) {
          // some logick

          scanner = getBluetoothAdapter().bluetoothLeScanner
          scanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, this)
      }
  }
    fun getBluetoothAdapter(): BluetoothAdapter {
      return Objects.requireNonNull(
          getBluetoothManager().adapter,
          "Cannot get BluetoothAdapter"
      )
  }
  fun getBluetoothManager(): BluetoothManager {
      return Objects.requireNonNull(
          context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as 
    BluetoothManager,
          "Cannot get BluetoothManager"
      )
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).